# How do you retain trailing newlines when storing command output in a variable?

Tags: bash, variables

Is it possible to retain trailing newlines when storing the output of a command in a variable?

```
$ echo "foo
" # newline appears after foo
foo

$ MYVAR="$(echo "foo
")"
$ echo "${MYVAR}" # newline is stripped
foo
$
```

Comment: The `bash` man page clearly states that trailing newlines are removed from the output of a command inside a command substitution. There may be a better way to solve your problem than dealing with a parameter with a multi-lined value. What is the bigger task you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to know how to remove the first line from a variable that may contain trailing spaces while keeping the trailing spaces. Barring that, I am keeping a FIFO queue of items by pulling them off the top and pushing them on the bottom, where an item is a string that may be empty. I suppose this could also be accomplished using arrays.

Comment: Yeah, an array is way better.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Except I can add an item to this list without knowing it's current size: `MYVAR="${MYVAR} new item"`

Comment: @Cory `array+=("new item")`

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks. I just barely found that as well.

Comment: Regardless, I would still like to know if this is possible using the above approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a sentinel to the end of the stream:

```
$ my_var=$'foo\n\n'
$ captured=$( echo -n "$my_var"; echo -n "x" )
```

which you then remove:

```
$ captured=${captured%x}
$ echo "$captured"
```